# Normalized confidence measure of point from normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a 1D normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Given a new number $x$, I want to assign a confidence value to how likely $x$ is to have been drawn from the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$

1 - the cdf gives me $P(X > x)$ but I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for.

Any help is much appreciated

**EDIT**

Just another thought, the value $x$ will fall on one side of the mean, or on the mean itself. Essentially I want to define a confidence measure that decreases to 0 as the point moves away from the mean, and is 1 at the mean. So what about $0.5 + f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the pdf of the normal distribution between the bounds $\mu$ and $x$?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you get $x = \mu$. While you could say that's the *most* likely possible value for $x$ if it did come from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, you're not in a position to say that the probability that it *did* come from that normal is anything. To make such a statement would require something like a Bayesian point of view, and then you're dealing with inference conditional on your priors relating to *what else it might be coming from*.

In the absence of that, you can talk about how *relatively* likely two values of $x$ would be. That comes from the ratio of how probable they'd be under the model, like so $f(x_1|\mu,\sigma)/f(x_2|\mu,\sigma)$.

Comment: I have used $f(x|\mu,\sigma)/f(\mu|\mu,\sigma)$

Answer (score 1):

For a measure based on distance from the mean, try this:

Use 2P[X > x] for x > mean, 
    2P[X < x] for x < mean, and
         1    for x = mean